# How to check if a list contains a group of values in any order - Python

Tags: python-2.7

i'm writing a program that takes a triangular number, and finds a collection of up to three other triangular numbers whose sum is equal to the first one. All the code i have currently is below. If you run the program and type 10 for example for the input it will print out a list of the first 10 triangular numbers along with combinations of smaller triangular numbers whose sum is the 10th one.

what i'm trying to do, is to prevent the same answer from coming up in a different order if you use the 10 example again, the output is:

6 + 21 + 28 = 55

6 + 28 + 21 = 55

10 + 45 = 55

21 + 6 + 28 = 55

21 + 28 + 6 = 55

28 + 6 + 21 = 55

28 + 21 + 6 = 55

45 + 10 = 55

but obviously 6 + 21 + 28 = 55 is the same as 6 + 28 + 21 = 55, also 10 + 45 = 55 and 45 + 10 = 55 and so on... they're just in a different order. So does anyone know a simple way i could check to make sure the group of values isn't repeating in any order? If you still have questions about what i'm trying to do, just post a comment and ill try and explain this better.

## Code:

```
def f(x):
    newX = 0
    for i in range(0,x):
        newX = newX + i
    return newX

def main():
    lst = []
    inpt = input("What number triangular number would you like to test: ")
    for i in range(2,inpt+2):
        x = f(i)
        lst.append(x)
    find(x, lst)

#x is the triangular number, lst is list of all of them up to it
def find(x, lst):
    a = 0
    b = 0
    c = 0
    length = len(lst)
    print(lst)
    last = lst[length-1]
    for j in lst:
       a = j

        for k in lst:
            b = k
            if(a+b == x):
                if(a != b):
                    print(str(a) + " + " + str(b) + " = " + str(x))

            for i in lst:
                c = i
                if(a+b+c == x):
                    if(a != b and a != c and b != c):

                        print(str(a) + " + " + str(b) + " + " + str(c) + " = " + str(x))
     print

main()
```

Comment: Use a [`set`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### a hint

```
>>> [1, 2, 3] == [1, 3, 2]
False
>>> sorted([1, 3, 2])
[1, 2, 3]
>>> [1, 2, 3] == sorted([1, 3, 2])
True
```

Canonicalization is the process whereby there is one-and-only-one ordering for a set of elements. This makes comparisons between different orderings of the the same elements become equal.